# converting a php function into a bash string

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script that adds a line into a php function like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\Corporate\CorporateContract',
        'App\Repositories\Corporate\EloquentCorporateRepository');
}
```

Here's my code:

```
function bindContractToRepository {
   sed -i -e '/register()\n/a \ \n\t\t'${repoBinding}' \n\t\t\t\t ' ./app/Providers/${repoName}${provider}.php 2> /dev/null
}
bindContractToRepository
```

I actually want my code to come inside the function itself like the example at the top.

NB. I can't specify a particular line because the line number varies with different version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In general* it is very difficult to detect PHP function boundaries without a parser.

We can do the parser's job in Bash: iterate the code line by line, solve the opening and closing braces etc. until we get the range of lines covered by this function and, finally, replace it with new content. We can do the same using the [`sed` commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) (in this case will likely look less readable than an assembly code).

But we already have a PHP parser! Why not use it?

### Example

The following PHP CLI script accepts:

- PHP input file (where we are going to replace a method/function);
- PHP Method/function name
- PHP code string for the replacement as a string, or dash(the standard input)

**replace-method.php**

```php
<?php
function usage($error = false) {
  global $argv;

  $str = <<<EOS
USAGE: php {$argv[0]} OPTIONS

OPTIONS:

-h, --help         Print help message
-i, --input-file   Input PHP file
-m, --method       PHP function/method name, e.g.:
                   my_func, MyClass::myMethod
-c, --code         The new PHP code including the function/method declaration.
                   String of code, or dash ('-') meaning the standard input.

EXAMPLE:

php {$argv[0]} -i source/file.php -m 'MyClass::register' -c - <<ENDOFPHP
  public function register()
  {
    echo time();
  }

ENDOFPHP

Replaces the code of 'MyClass::register' method with new code from the standard input
in source/file.php.

EOS;
  fprintf($error ? STDERR : STDOUT, $str);
  exit((int)!$error);
}

if (false === ($opt = getopt('hi:m:c:', ['help', 'input-file:', 'method:', 'code:']))) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Failed to parse options\n");
  usage(true);
}


if (isset($opt['h']) || isset($opt['help']))
  usage();

// Using PHP7 Null coalescing operator
$file = $opt['i'] ?? $opt['input-file'] ?? null;
if (!file_exists($file)) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "File '$file' does not exist\n");
  usage(true);
}

$new_code = $opt['c'] ?? $opt['code'] ?? null;
if (!$new_code) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Code option expected\n");
  usage(true);
}
if ($new_code == '-')
  $new_code = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

$method = $opt['m'] ?? $opt['method'] ?? null;
if (!$method) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Method option expected\n");
  usage(true);
}

// You most likely want to include project's autoloading file instead.
// (You might accept it as a CLI argument, too.)
require_once $file;

$rf = strpos($method, '::') ?
  new ReflectionMethod($method) :
  new ReflectionFunction($method);
$start_line = $rf->getStartLine();
$end_line = $rf->getEndLine();

$lines = file($file);

$code = implode(array_slice($lines, 0, $start_line - 1)) .
  $new_code . implode(array_slice($lines, $end_line));

file_put_contents($file, $code);
```

Suppose we have `path/to/file.php` with `A` class and its `register` method:

```
<?php
class A
{
  public function register()
  {
    echo 'aaaa';
  }
}
```

We can replace the code of `A::register` method in a Bash as follows:

```
php replace-method.php -i path/to/file.php -m 'A::register' -c - <<ENDOFPHP
  public function register()
  {
    echo 'something new';
  }
ENDOFPHP
```

I've used Bash here document for input. You can use any kind of the shell redirection, for instance:

```
generate_php_code | php 1.php -i file.php -m 'A::register' -c -
```

Comment: This line keeps returning and error.... " $rf = new ReflectionMethod('A', 'register'); " and here's the error it keeps returning " syntax error near unexpected token `(' ". Don't know why. I would like to get cleared about the location of this code you showed me. It's meant to be inside my bash script right? Sorry about my questions, i'm a novice at this.

Comment: @Ohssie, that's weird. Reflection is a part of the PHP core. Right, I suggest moving this code replacement logic into a PHP CLI script, then call it from Bash. I've added sample code in the answer.